# How to stub S4 class method using mockery

Tags: r, r-s4

I have an S4 class which has a method that takes a logger. I want to mock that logger.
Ordinarily I would do something like:

```
stub(function_being_tested, "flog.info", mock())
function_being_tested("logger", args)
```

Applying that in the case of a class method:

```
stub(function_being_tested, "flog.info", mock())
function_being_tested("logger", args)
```

where function_being_tested was in my environment previously results in an "unable to find an inherited method for function "function_being_tested" for signature "ClassWhichHasTheMethod" error. So whereas before I used "stub" this method was available, when I add a stub it now disappears.
I can:

```
stub(ClassWhichHasTheMethod, "flog.info", mock(), depth=3)
function_being_tested("logger", args)
```

which doesn't give an error but then that's because it doesn't use the mock at all... Any ideas?